# What happened to Package Restore between 2.7 and 2.8?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

We're using an internal feed for a number of packages. Today we noticed that Package Restore was no longer working. Every package failed with an error along the lines of this:

> Unable to find version '...' of package '...'.

The project with issues had its first commit on 2013-10-04, at the time NuGet had version 2.7
Multiple people successfully cloned the source control repo, which had no binaries at all, and nobody recalls any problems with package restore. So either all of us are going insane, or this was working fine.
When I try to do a new clone today and update to that very first commit, I get the error above. Same thing with the most recent commit. This is with NuGet 2.8

[These are the docs concerning Package Restore changes in 2.7](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore):

> Before any of the above steps are taken however, NuGet verifies that
>   consent is given on two levels:
>
> 1. Visual Studio is configured to 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'
> 2. Visual Studio is configured to 'Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio'

Both items are checked in the VS options.

> This approach to package restore offers several advantages:
>
> 1. No need to enable it for your project or solution. Visual Studio will automatically download missing packages before your projects are
>      built and team members don't need to understand NuGet Package Restore.

Yet this is exactly how we managed to solve the problem today: right clicking the solution and enabling Package Restore. This resulted in changes on multiple levels.

**.csproj level**

```
+    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
+    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
```

**.sln level**

```
+Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = ".nuget", ".nuget", "{6FE1C500-523A-4E05-B72E-28F14DEDB055}"
+   ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
+       .nuget\NuGet.Config = .nuget\NuGet.Config
+       .nuget\NuGet.exe = .nuget\NuGet.exe
+       .nuget\NuGet.targets = .nuget\NuGet.targets
+   EndProjectSection
+EndProject
```

And lastly, the creation of `.nuget\NuGet.Config`, `.nuget\nuget.exe` and `.nuget\NuGet.targets`.

As a test I've also created a new solution and project. Now I

1. add one of the internal packages
2. build
3. close the solution
4. delete the `packages`, `bin` and `obj` directories (like our ignore file does)
5. open the solution
6. rebuild, and get the error mentioned in the beginning of the question

When I repeat these steps with a package from the official repo, everything works fine. No errors at all.

I've went over the release notes for [2.7.1](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.7.1), [2.7.2](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.7.2) and [2.8.0](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8) but I don't see anything related to this. What's going on?

Comment: You said it works without error on the official repo; is perhaps your internal repo dead?  Or maybe it needs to be updated to support the latest NuGet (maybe the feed specs changed?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [confirmed bug](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4032) in the current release of NuGet, but it's fixed in the nightly builds.

Workaround for now is to set *Package source* to *All* in the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the following issue: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4000

Related to this issue, the nuget.exe client would not follow redirects, so if your internal NuGet server is returning a 302 when attempting to download a package, the client would not follow it and result in nothing happening. It's worth double-checking with a Fiddler trace to see if the VS extension has the same behavior.